# A complicated reshape of a 3d matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, reshape

I have a 3D matrix of size `12,3,43`:

```
val(:,:,1) =

9.8226   -0.5904   -0.2306
1.9440   -0.4382   -0.4923
0.0519    0.6613    0.6225
1.7321   -0.4460   -0.5919
0.0833    0.6556    0.5539
9.8226    9.8226    9.8226
9.8729    0.5276   58.2741
3.2360    0.0003    0.1039
0.0720    0.9859    0.7473
0.4310    0.0223    0.0298
0.3656   -0.4085   -1.8384
1.0401   -0.4198    0.0106


...

val(:,:,43) =

   16.2780    2.1931    0.4593
    3.1613    1.3327    0.5388
    0.0016    0.1826    0.5900
    2.7613    1.1525    0.5731
    0.0058    0.2491    0.5666
   16.2780   16.2780   16.2780
   15.2386   12.3233  -71.4624
    6.6782    0.1105    0.0858
    0.0098    0.7396    0.7696
    1.1318    0.2056    0.0357
   -0.7161    0.1360    0.5850
    0.7256    0.7578    0.6312
```

First I would like to change the direction of each matrix, like so, I do this using `matrix(:,:,1).'`:

```
    9.8226    1.9440    0.0519    1.7321    0.0833    9.8226    9.8729    3.2360    0.0720    0.4310    0.3656    1.0401
   -0.5904   -0.4382    0.6613   -0.4460    0.6556    9.8226    0.5276    0.0003    0.9859    0.0223   -0.4085   -0.4198
   -0.2306   -0.4923    0.6225   -0.5919    0.5539    9.8226   58.2741    0.1039    0.7473    0.0298   -1.8384    0.0106
```

Then I would like to create a new 3D matrix which gathers the top row from each entry, the second and the third, etc. So in the end I would have a 3D matrix of size `12,43,3`.

I have tried `permute` and `reshape` but I cannot seem to get them to work for a task of this nature.

A small toy example:

```
a = [1 11; 2 22; 3 33]
b = [4 43; 5 55; 6 66]
c = [7 76; 8 88; 9 90]
d = [10 101; 11 111; 12 121];
Z = cat(3,a,b,c,d)  % The 3D initial matrix
```

Which should be transformed into

```
Z_hope(:,:,1) =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
    10    11    12


Z_hope(:,:,2) =

    11    22    33
    43    55    66
    76    88    90
   101   111   121
```

Comment: To go from 12x3x43 to 12x43x3 you only need to perlite the last two dimensions.  It sure what all the other complexities in your question do? `permute(in,[1,3,2])`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I am still struggling with this, this does not provide Z_hope and instead provides a 4x3

Comment: That makes no sense. Unless you put in a 4x3 matrix.

Comment: Sorry with my simple example, I get you now, Thanks!